# Kendo DropDownList Preserve Whitespace in Option

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

I am using Kendo UI for JQuery/AngularJS.

I have the following `<select>` control defined:

```
                            <select
                                kendo-drop-down-list
                               k-options="myOptions">
                            </select>
```

I have a datasource returning JSON with VALUE representing the value for an `<option>`, and TEXT representing the label for the option.

Unfortunately, the VALUE returns with leading spaces, meant to represent a hierarchy:

```
[
{VALUE: 1, TEXT: 'Accounting'},
{VALUE: 2, TEXT: '    Accounts Payable'}, 
{VALUE: 3, TEXT: '    Accounts Receivable'}
]
```

This should correspond to an group of options like the following:

```
<option value="1">Accounting</option>
<option value="2">    Accounts Payable</option>
<option value="3">    Accounts Receivable</option>
```

Below is my definition of options:

```
                $scope.myOptions = {
                    autoWidth: true,
                    autoBind: false,
                    dataTextField: 'TEXT',
                    dataValueField: 'VALUE',
                    dataSource: {
                        transport: {
                            read: {
                                url: urlToREST,
                                dataType: 'json',
                                type: 'POST',
                                contentType: "application/json"
                            },
                            // needed to send params as JSON
                            parameterMap: function (data, type) {
                                const req = {
                                    "QUERY_ID": $scope.queryId
                                };

                                return JSON.stringify(req);

                            }
                        },

                        schema: {
                            type: "json",
                           data: "resultData"
                        }

                    }
                };
```

I need to represent multiple levels of a hierarchy in the options. I felt the best way would be to use Javascript to dynamically create a `<pre>` section, but it's not working.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Why are you having the hierarchy being represented by "   " before the name?  Are you trying to do something similar to this https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treelist/index or am I missing something?

Comment: You can preserve the whitespaces via CSS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

Comment: @Kevin I needed a hierarchy represented in a select box as a visual cue for someone selecting a value.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up dynamically computing the amount of whitespace required to represent the hierarchy, then adding `&nbsp;` for each space (the number of spaces is a parameter returned by the remote service call):

```
function indent(spaceCount) {
    return '&nbsp;'.repeat(spaceCount);
}

$scope.options = {
    dataTextField: 'TEXT',
    dataValueField: 'VALUE',
    template: function(dataItem) {
        return kendo.template(indent(dataItem.spaces -1) *4) + '#: DESCRIPTION #')(dataItem);
    },
    dataSource: {
        transport: {
            read: {
                // read definition
            },
            // needed to send JSON parameters to the query
            parameterMap: function(data, type) {
               const req = {
                   'QUERY_ID': $scope.queryId
               };
               return JSON.stringify(req);
            }
        },
        schema: {
            type: 'json',
            data: 'resultData'
        }
    }
};
```

The indent function could have been done inline. This could also probably have been refactored into an AngularJS service as well.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the template function and specified a table within the template

Which allows me to specify width for each row

```cs
@(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(model => model.PersonId)
.DataTextField("FullName")
.DataValueField("Id")
.Value("")
.Filter(FilterType.Contains)
.MinLength(2)
.AutoBind(true)
.Template("<table><tr><td width='200px'>#: data.FullName #</td><td width='100px'> - #: data.EmpId #</td></tr></table>")
.DataSource(s =>
```